# Laravel Eloquent Query With OR WHERE Condition

Tags: laravel, eloquent, where-clause

I am using Laravel 6 & mysql 7

I have below query

```
$tasks = Task::where('deleted_at', null)->where('company_id',$company_id);
$tasks = $tasks->where('created_by',$user_id);
$tasks = $tasks->orWhereIn('id',$task_ids);
```

It generates below raw query when i print it

```
SELECT * FROM `tasks` WHERE `deleted_at` IS NULL AND  `company_id` = 25 AND `created_by` = 20 OR 
`id` IN(112,...215) ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Now Id 112 is deleted but still showing in result, although i have where('deleted_at', null) condition but it is not working

I want to apply all other conditions on `$task_ids` as well

How this can be achieved with optimized query?

***UPDATED***: Here is complete scenario

I want to select all records which is created by me or assigned to me. Here is my complete code.

```
 $tasks = Task::where('deleted_at', null)->where('company_id',$company_id);
 $tasks = $tasks->where('created_by',$user_id);
 $task_ids = TaskUser::where('user_id',$user_id)->pluck('task_id')->all();
 $tasks = $tasks->orWhereIn('id',$task_ids);
```

Comment: `where A and B and C or D`, so the `id=112` record is successfully passed by condition D.

Comment: so if you want `condition A (deleted_at is null)` put effect on `condition D (where in 112...)`. u can change your code to `where A and (B and C or D)` or `where (A and B and C) or (A and D)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the AND operator has a higher [precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html) than OR, which basically means that AND "sticks" together more than OR does. You query basically is interpredeted like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `tasks` 
WHERE 
    (`deleted_at` IS NULL AND  `company_id` = 25 AND `created_by` = 20) 
  OR 
    ( `id` IN(112,...215) )
```

I am not entirly sure wheter you actually want to OR anything. If you really want to apply all conditions, you just need to change the `orWhereIn` to a `whereIn`.

---

In case you want all not-deleted tasks, that EITHER belong to a company and a auser OR  whose id is in the list, you would need to update your query like this:

```
$tasks = Task::where('deleted_at', null);

$tasks = $tasks->where(function($q) use ($user_id, $task_ids){

    $q->where(function($q2) use ($user_id, $task_ids) {
        $q2->where('created_by',$user_id)
           ->where('company_id',$company_id);
    })
      ->orWhereIn('id',$task_ids);
});
```

which should result in this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tasks` 
WHERE `deleted_at` IS NULL AND ( 
  ( `company_id` = 25 AND `created_by` = 20 )
  OR
  `id` IN(112,...215) 
)
```

There is actually a chapter about [parameter grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#parameter-grouping) in the excellent laravel documentation as well.

Comment: I can not use whereIn because i want to select records created by me + records assigned to me.  I have updated my question

Comment: @MuhammadAli In this case you need to move the company part out of both closures. The generall idea how to group parameters remains the same though. Did you manage get the results you wanted? If not I can update my answer.